# How do I close a branch i accidentally reopened?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm quite new to github, and while switching between pc's i chose the wrong branch to work on...

The purple branch was meant to be a new branch from my master:
[branch opened from other branch instead of master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0F7q.png)

Is there any way to delete the branch, or maybe move it to the master branch

**UPDATE:** forgot to mention that i do not know how to work with the terminal yet, so i'd like advice on how to fix this within the github website.

Sorry if there is any similar question, i couldn't find an answer my self.

Answer (score 2):

You can just merge your change into master, then delete the unwanted branch.
Say your unwanted branch is branch-b, and you are current at this branch

```
// Commit all your change
git add .
git commit -m "Your commit message"

// Change to master branch
git checkout master

// merge changes from branch-b to master
git merge branch-b

// finally delete branch-b, as it is no longer needed and all changes already merged into master
git branch -d branch-b
```

Comment: forgot to mention that i do not know how to work with the terminal yet, so i'd like advice on how to fix this within the github website, but thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I don't know how do it from within github. You may need to study how to do it from the terminal, then push the result to github